# Calling a function in C with variables not being outputted

Tags: c, xcode, function

This is how it looks now but it's telling me that the variable 'result' is unused. Why is this? I think I've figured out the use of the function in this program but I can't configure everything quite yet. Still need some help, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double computeSomething(unsigned int maxDamage, unsigned int minDamage,
                        double playerArmor, double actualDamage);

int main(void){

    double playerHealth, playerArmor, actualDamage, result = 0;
    unsigned int minDamage, maxDamage;

    printf("Enter Player Health:     ");
    scanf("%lf", &playerHealth);
    printf("Enter Player Armor (0.0 - 1.0):   ");
    scanf("%lf", &playerArmor);
    printf("Enter Minimum Damage Dealt:  ");
    scanf("%u", &minDamage);
    printf("Enter Maximum Damage Dealt:   ");
    scanf("%u", &maxDamage);

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    while (playerHealth > 0) {

        double result = computeSomething(maxDamage, minDamage, playerArmor,     actualDamage);
        playerHealth -= actualDamage;

        printf("Current Player Health:%.2lf\tDamage Dealt: %.2lf\t",      playerHealth, actualDamage);
        if (playerHealth > 0){
            printf("Alive: 1\n");
        } else {
            printf("Alive: 0\n");
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

double computeSomething(unsigned int maxDamage, unsigned int minDamage,
                        double playerArmor, double actualDamage)
{
     actualDamage = ((rand() % (maxDamage-minDamage + 1)) + minDamage) * (1 -     playerArmor);

    return actualDamage;
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: I am failing to parse the question text. Please improve your wording.

Comment: The problem is that I can't create a function to call for. That's literally all I need to do. I tried creating a function that'll compute just the actualDamage or just the playerHealth but the minDamage and maxDamage throws me off. I'm not sure if you get it but creating any functions to call for is the only thing I'm looking for.

Comment: How can't you create it? is your source file read-only? haven't you the access rights to modify files in your system? Have you a valid account to do whatever you want?  Is the compiler complainting about something in your code? Do you have problems building the program? Have you tried to plug the power socket to turn on your computer? Have you lost your keys at your workplace and you cannot get access to the computer?  An error message from the compiler (or more specific problem description) would be nice to make a diagnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit 3***

Change your prototype from:

```
double computeSomething(unsigned int maxDamage, unsigned int minDamage,
                        double playerArmor, double actualDamage);
```

To:

```
double computeSomething(unsigned int maxDamage, unsigned int minDamage,
                        double playerArmor, double *actualDamage);
```

Call it like this:

```
float res;
computeSomething(34, 15, 30.5, &res);
```

See my latest example below for how to modify the result in the actual function.

***I can't create a function to call for. That's literally all I need to do.***

This defines a function that is *called* from `main()`;
(For something more specific, describe it specifically)

***EDIT***

Added a function that is passed values, computes something, and returns results.  Perhaps you can apply the principles here to your problem.  (I do not fully understand your needs from the description you have provided)

```
//prototypes
void PrintSomething(char *str);
float compute_something(float x, float y, float z);//per clarification in comments above  
void return_through_param(float x, float y, float *result);
int main(void)
{
    PrintSomething("Hello World\n");
    //function that can return something
    float result = compute_something(10.0, 3.5, .002);
    printf("Here are the results: %f\n", result); 

    //for Edit 2:
    return_through_param(10, .0001, &result);
    printf("This is the new result: %f\n", result);

    return 0;
}  

void PrintSomething(char *str)
{
     printf(str);
}
//Edit - Added this function
float compute_something(float x, float y, float z)
{
    return x*y/z;
}  

//Edit 2 - added this function that passes pointer, for output
void return_through_param(float x, float y, float *result)
{
     return *result = x/y;
}
```

Comment: I see how that works but I am confused regarding how I would create a function to compute something like actualDamage within my program. Thanks.

Comment: You've defined `result` twice, once in the top of your main() function, then again when you use it with compute_something.  Remove ***float*** from in front of the line ***result = compute_something(10.0, 3.5, .002);***

Comment: In functions, there are `return` values, and input values, and ***output** values:  see my edit to see how to get _output_ from a function parameter.

Comment: I used the return function strategy you showed me in your edit for my computeSomething function. I'm not sure where it's going wrong. Apologize for my lack of understanding.

Comment: Functions can have a return, and function can have an output.  You may be confusing them.  A void function for example has no return value, but it _can have an output parameter, usually in the form of a pointer _...(int x, int *result);_ ***1st param = input, 2nd param = output***